# git rebase continue creates commit out of everything that's in index

Tags: git

Today during rebasing I got a conflict. Conflict resolutions took a while and after conflicts have been resolved I for some reason thought that rebase was completed. Then I applied some stash and continued development. In the middle of development I noticed that git says that rebasing is in progress. So I executed `git rebase --continue` which resulted in the commit of everything that was unstashed. So is it correct to assume that `git rebase --continue` will create new commit using current state of index when this command is executed? For example, I tried to add completely new file to git index during rebasing and `rebase --continue` committed that file although the file wasn't present in the commit that was being rebased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely up to you how to resolve the conflict before issuing `git rebase --continue`. Rebase will expect that after resolving the conflict you will have the changes ready in the stage, and it will create a commit with the original message for you. It will even complain if you have empty stage and working directory.

Similar concept is used in interactive mode when you select a commit for edit, [example](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_splitting_commits)

Comment: thanks, but in the examples you mentioned a user is expected to do commits himself - _Commit the now-current index with..._, while I didn't make commit myself, git did it when I executed `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: true, I these cases are different indeed. Rebase remembers that you stopped because of the conflict and expects you to have it resolved and will create a commit itself from the workdir state. More than that, it will complain if you have no changes (clear working dir).

Comment: aha, that what I thought. Just wanted confirmation. Thanks!